Assuming a constant centripetal force, why does angular velocity change when the radius changes?
I've heard different explanations on this with torque/angular momentum, and also via conservation of energy (where since $F_c$ is the same and $r$ changes, then the angular velocity $\omega$ changes the other way), but I'm still not entirely satisfied with this reasoning and I feel like I don't have a perfect understanding on this.
Is there a more intuitive/conceptual way to explain why angular velocity changes when radius changes? As the title says, the basic assumption here is that the centripetal force remains constant.

It doesn't. That's the definition of UCM.

Sorry the original title of the post was worded differently to what I was trying to ask

Angular momentum conservation perhaps?

You need fix the title and the contents.  As written your question is unclear as when the angular velocity is supposed to change.

 Intuitive, non-rigorous argument 
What follows is a geometrical, intuitive and not completely rigorous argument. Consider the following diagram, where I've drawn two particles undergoing UCM. The red lines indicate the "true" trajectory, which is obviously not exactly along the circle but you can imagine these segments to be infinitesimally small so that would take care of that point.

So, let's start by looking at the particle on the smaller radius. In the absence of a centripetal force, it would have moved along the blue line and "fly off" on that tangent. However, the centripetal force, indicated by the little green arrow, deflects the particle and keeps it on the circle. Thus, in the indicated interval of time, the particle velocity changes so as to keep it on the circular trajectory. Great, we know that's how centripetal forces work in UCM.
Now however, let's for the sake of the argument, make the assumption that the particle on the larger radius, is moving with exactly the same angular speed. This in turn implies its tangential velocity is larger than the particle on the smaller radius. This is clear once you see it traversed a longer arclength during the same interval of time. Now, if that is so, and we insist that it's also undergoing UCM, the centripetal force in green now clearly has to be larger to deflect it from its own blue tangent, back to the circular trajectory. Since both the motion on the inner and the outward circle are by assumption occurring during the same interval of time, a larger centripetal force is required to deflect the particle with the larger tangential speed.
Therefore, we have arrived at a contradiction with the assumption that the centripetal force is constant, and the only resolution is to conclude that the particle on the larger radius moves with a smaller velocity, thus subtending a smaller angle at the same time, as shown in the following diagram:

Since $\alpha < \beta$ and these are angles subtended at equal times, this in turn implies the particle on the larger radius has a smaller angular velocity, which concludes the argument.

 The more formal approach 
Assuming you're talking about changing the radius from $r_\mathrm{i}$ to $r_\mathrm{f}$, where in both radii the particle experiences the same centripetal force, this force is in general equal to $m\omega^2 r$ for any radius $r$ (when in UCM), so we must have:
$$ m\omega_\mathrm{i}^2r_\mathrm{i} = m\omega_\mathrm{f}^2r_\mathrm{f} $$
Because the force didn't change when we moved from radius $r_\mathrm{i}$ to radius $r_\mathrm{f}$.
This in turn gives:
$$ \omega_\mathrm{f} = \sqrt{\frac{r_\mathrm{i}}{r_\mathrm{f}}}\ \omega_\mathrm{i} $$
So observe that:

$r_\mathrm{i} > r_\mathrm{f} \Longrightarrow \omega_\mathrm{f} > \omega_\mathrm{i} $ (angular speed increases)
$r_\mathrm{i} < r_\mathrm{f} \Longrightarrow \omega_\mathrm{f} < \omega_\mathrm{i} $ (angular speed decreases)
$r_\mathrm{i} = r_\mathrm{f} \Longrightarrow \omega_\mathrm{f} = \omega_\mathrm{i} $ (angular speed remains the same, of course)

Which confirms the "intuitive" argument as well.

A object can rotate around a axis only if there is a centripetal force acting on that object.But in any elliptic motion the centripetal force is always normal to the direction of the motion so it doesnt do any work->momentum has to be conserved.If a object goes from orbit A which is at a distance r1 from the center to a orbit B which is at a distance r2 from the center then since momentum is conserved ω1r1=ω2r2->
r2/r1=ω1/ω2

Angular momentum, which is r x p or r x (mv) tends to stay conserved unless and until an external force is applied to the rotating body. it's similar to conservation of linear momentum, you may wanna call it the first law of newton. now when the spinning body, let's say the ballet dancer widens her hands her momentum of inertia increases it which can only be compensated by a reduced angular velocity. L(angular momentum) = I * omega. I is the moment of inertia which tells us how the mass is actually distributed along the axis of rotation.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
